# Vue3 reactive array from a get defined property?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have an object set such as :

```
user = {
    name: 'Bill',
    addresses: [1, 2, 3]
}

addresses = {
    1: { zipcode: '91802', city: 'Los Angeles', country: 'US' },
    2: { zipcode: '06390', city: 'New York', country: 'US' },
    3: { zipcode: '94301', city: 'Palo Alto', country: 'US' }
}
```

I modify the object such as :

```
user._addresses = user.addresses
Object.defineProperties(document, {
    addresses: {
        get () {
            return user._addresses.map(id => addresses[id])
        }
    }
})
```

The issue is that if I now update `_addresses`, the `addresses` object is not automatically updated.

Such as:

```
user._addresses = [1, 2]
```

The interface does not update to reflect the changes.

I tried to play with `ref`, `toRef`, `reactive` from Vue3 but I honestly don't know where to place them in order to have a reactivity on `addresses` whenever I change `_addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The issue is that a Proxy works on an array as long as it is not overriden.

So doing

```
proxy_array = []
```

Will erase the proxy and replace it with a basic array!

So far, the best way I found to keep the Proxy (and thus, the reactivity) is to clear the array then add the items back, one by one:

```
proxy_array.splice(0, proxy_array.length)
new_array.forEach(item => proxy_array.push(item))
```

If there's a better solution for that, I'm interested!